# MixItUp not working on Select box (works with button)

Tags: javascript, php, mixitup

I need to filter a MixItUp based on the selection of a dropbox.  I have a physical button working, but when I try to change it to a select box my code fails.

Here is a functioning button that properly fires the MixItUp filter:

```
<button class="filter btn red" data-filter=".2" data-parent="#plan_list" href="#2" data-toggle="collapse" onclick="set_plan("test","2")" id="plan-2"><i class="fa fa-tag margin-right-10"></i>test</button>
```

The function fires on change, but the filter is not being applied. (I have a custom function that fires, so I know the call is working).

My code is based off this codepen: http://codepen.io/patrickkunka/pen/btCim

Here is the JS for the change:

```
$(function(){
    var $filterSelect = $('#FilterSelect'),
    $container = $('#Container');
    $container.mixItUp();
    $filterSelect.on('change', function(){
       $container.mixItUp('filter', '.'+this.value);
       set_plan('test',this.value); //custom function working properly
    });
});
```

In the JS above this.value is the plan_id .  I have to add the '.'+this.value in the code above here so that other functions can work on the clean plan id.  I have tested this code and that part works so I know its not the issue.

Here is the code for the select (php):

```
<select id="FilterSelect">
<? foreach ($plans as $plan) {echo '<option value="'.$plan['id'].'">'.$plan['name'].'</option> ';?>
</select>
```

Can anyone tell me what I missed?  The button works, the select does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the problem.  Its not in the code listed above:

I was missing the container id for the html categories to be filtered.

```
<div class="Container">
```

should have been:

```
<div id="Container" >
```

Stupid simple mistake, I reviewed this code several times and saw it, but in my mind read it as id not class.

New question, how do I fix the bugs in my brain????!!!